# How to call function after routing in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's say there is a website with routes: 
/routeA,
/routeB
...
/routeZ

Each of those routes render a ComponentA, ComponentB ... ComponentZ

How to run a particular piece of code no matter which route has been reached?

The piece of code is irrelevant. It could be console.log("Awesome stackoverflow")

Obviously, in each component I could call useEffect and call the piece of code there. However, this is repetitive since I would have to write Z useEffect for the Z components we have. 
Instead, I am looking for a way to execute the piece of code without needing to repeate code through all components.

Comment: route is reaching inside some component, for example App, so in useEffect  or ComponentDidMount you can run any code you like

Comment: or please specify what this code should do

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Thank you. I am looking for a way to execute the code without calling it from the components. I updated the question.

Comment: yes, but answer is the same - no need to call it inside route component, call it in their parent component

Comment: it is a nice case for hoc @fjplaurr

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `useLocation` hook that is a part of `react-use`
I can confirm this bit of code works using `react-router`, and this useEffect has to reside in the same component with your `<Router>` component, for me this was `App.js`

```
 const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    // code to run on every route
  }, [location]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//if you are using class
class YourComponent extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount = () => {
        //your logic here
    }
}

//if you are using hook
const YourComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
       //your logic here
    },[])
}
```